# get UIView origin with aspect to screen size iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, screen-size

I want to get UIView origin points from one device and save that points to server. On other device, I want to show UIView at same origin points. The problem is coming with screen size.

Suppose I get UIView position in iPhone 11 and save it on server. Now, I get saved position from server on iPhone 6s device and show UIView on that position. UIView location is not same on both devices because of screen sizes are different.

Is there any solution for it? 
Is there any way to get origin points aspect with screen size that will be fine for all screen sizes?

Comment: As I am new here, If anybody want more explanation, I am here to explain

Comment: Try with converting to Screen coordinations `yourView.convert(yourView.frame.origin, to: UIScreen.main)`

Comment: I tried it. It's fine if both devices have same screen size. when screen size is different then problem occur

Comment: Use the normalization function that will convert the specific position to a "percentage" position relative to the screen size.

Comment: please can you write example code it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

1st device

```swift
let yourPositionOnView: CGPoint = ...
let screenPosition = yourView.convert(yourPositionOnView, to: UIScreen.main)
let relativePosition = CGPoint(
    x: screenPosition.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 
    y: screenPosition.y / UIScreen.main.bounds.height
)
```

2nd device

```swift
let screenPosition = CGPoint(
    x: relativePosition.x * UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 
    y: relativePosition.y * UIScreen.main.bounds.height
)
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you bro.